# Export a LaTeX table from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, latex, dataframe, pandas

Is there an easy way to export a data frame (or even a part of it) to LaTeX?

*I searched in google and was only able to find solutions using asciitables.*

Comment: In addition to the replies here, this question has an interesting approach too. Export to csv and then import the csv into latex: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54990/convert-numpy-array-into-tabular

Answer (score 109, accepted):

DataFrames have a `to_latex` (see the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html)) method:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5, 5)))
>>> df  
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.886864  0.518538  0.359964  0.167291  0.940414
1  0.834130  0.022920  0.265131  0.059002  0.530584
2  0.648019  0.953043  0.263551  0.595798  0.153969
3  0.207003  0.015721  0.931170  0.045044  0.432870
4  0.039886  0.898780  0.728195  0.112069  0.468485

>>> print(df.to_latex())
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{} &         0 &         1 &         2 &         3 &         4 \\
\hline
0 &  0.886864 &  0.518538 &  0.359964 &  0.167291 &  0.940414 \\
1 &  0.834130 &  0.022920 &  0.265131 &  0.059002 &  0.530584 \\
2 &  0.648019 &  0.953043 &  0.263551 &  0.595798 &  0.153969 \\
3 &  0.207003 &  0.015721 &  0.931170 &  0.045044 &  0.432870 \\
4 &  0.039886 &  0.898780 &  0.728195 &  0.112069 &  0.468485 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

You can simply write this to a tex file.

By default latex will render this as:

[image: as it would appear in latex]

*Note: the `to_latex` (see the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html)) method offers several configuration options.*

Comment: does `to_latex()` support multi-indexing?

Comment: @TheChymera: Yes. I just tried multi columns, which seems to work. Multi indices look a little bit strange to me.

Comment: The option `float_format=lambda x: '%10.2f' % x` proved to be very useful in my case. Also, in LaTeX, I had to add `\usepackage{booktabs}`, as the output uses `\toprule` which requires it.

Comment: Great ! Does the reverse exists? I have a latex array and I would like to create a dataframe

Comment: Is there a way to end up with the pdf generated from the `latex` code?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to save it:

```
with open('mytable.tex', 'w') as tf:
     tf.write(df.to_latex())
```

Comment: Actually, you just need  `df.to_latex('mytable.tex')`

Answer (score 10):

Just write to a textfile. It's no magic:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(10), "b":range(10,20)})
with open("my_table.tex", "w") as f:
    f.write("\\begin{tabular}{" + " | ".join(["c"] * len(df.columns)) + "}\n")
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        f.write(" & ".join([str(x) for x in row.values]) + " \\\\\n")
    f.write("\\end{tabular}")
```

Comment: Although it is useful to show how easy it is to export tabular data to LaTeX using plain Python, it is of course much better to use existing facilities, i.e., `DataFrame.to_latex()` in this case.

Comment: Hi, I totally agree. My reasons were:
1. I started with pandas before version 0.9, where to_latex wasn't available
2. This might be useful when some adjustement is needed or someone wants to export to another format, e.g., XAML, custom XML or whatever. 
But thank you for your comment