# Formatting latex (to_latex) output

Tags: python, latex, pandas

I've read [about the `to_latex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380371/export-a-latex-table-from-pandas-dataframe/14383654#14383654) method, but it's not clear **how to use the formatters argument**.

I have some numbers which are **too long** and some which I want **thousand separators**.

*A side [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2924) for the `to_latex` method on multi-indexed tables, the indices are parsed together and it issues some `&`s in the latex output.*

Comment: From the answer below you can search for python formatting functions (too long has been mentioned, and perhaps see [here for thousand separators](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1823058/1240268)).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For a simple data frame. First, without formatters:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
              c1        c2
first   0.821354  0.936703
second  0.138376  0.482180

In [12]: print df.to_latex()
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
{} &        c1 &        c2 \\
\hline
first  &  0.821354 &  0.936703 \\
second &  0.138376 &  0.482180 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

*Copy-pasting the output (of `[12]`) to latex, we get: [image: latex without formatters]*

If we create two functions `f1` and `f2` and put them into `to_latex` as `formatters`:

```
def f1(x):
    return 'blah_%1.2f' % x

def f2(x):
    return 'f2_%1.2f' % x

In [15]: print df.to_latex(formatters=[f1, f2])
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
{} &        c1 &      c2 \\
\hline
first  & blah\_0.82 & f2\_0.94 \\
second & blah\_0.14 & f2\_0.48 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

*Copy-pasting the output to latex, we get:*
[image: latex with formatters f1 and f2]

Note: how the formatter function `f1` is applied to the first column and `f2` to the second.

Comment: I have written code to handle the following issues:

* Pandas Multi-indexes

* handling latex reserved characters in the table.  Standard pandas method leads to errors in latex compiling if '&', '%', '$', '#' etc are used in any of the cells. they need to be escaped

* also written code that can band the latex representation of the pandas dataframe (shading alternate rows)

* also autoformatting numbers 

Methods are tied up in in latex generating class that 'n wrote so difficult to post here as code is bit messy.  I am happy to post here if anyone need some help.

Comment: If you want to format only float columns, set the `float_format` parameter to your format function. You don't need to create a list of functions for that.