# How to format `to_latex()` output based on the content of different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069814/formatting-latex-to-latex-output). Assume I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 3], 'col2': [2, 1]})
```

from which I can get a Latex table as

```
df.to_latex()
```

I know I can pass a formatter for each columnm as illustrated, e.g., in the above question.
My question is: **How can I format the elements of `col1` based on the elements of `col2` and viceversa**?

Assume, for example, I want to add a plus sign to a cell, if its value is higher than that of the adjacent cell, getting the following result.

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
{} &  col1 &  col2 \\
\midrule
0 &     1 &     +2 \\
1 &     +3 &     1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `formatters` only accept functions that work on cell values without any information about the dataframe index/column. So it might not work for your purpose.

I would pre-format the data and pass to `to_latex`:

```
strs = np.array([['','+']]* len(df))
signs =  np.where(df['col1'].lt(df['col2']).values[:,None], strs,strs[:,::-1])

(signs + df.astype(str)).to_latex()
```

Output:

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
{} & col1 & col2 \\
\midrule
0 &    1 &   +2 \\
1 &   +3 &    1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```