# How to write Pandas MultiIndex Dataframe w/mean to ReportLab table

Tags: python, pandas, reportlab

I have merged two Pandas dataframes (course schedule and student evaluations) via an inner join.  I then produce a .groupby() dataframe of course section by course by instructor.  Lastly, I compute the .mean() for questions 1 through 4 and print the results.  How can I write these results, multiindex, column titles, and analysis, to a ReportLab Table for output to a pdf?

```
merged_df = pd.merge(left=evals_df, right=sched_df, left_on='Course', right_on='Course')
byInstructor_df = merged_df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']].groupby([merged_df['PRIMARY_INSTRUCTOR_NAME'], 
                        merged_df['COURSE_NUMBER'], merged_df['OFFERING_NUMBER']])
print(byInstructor_df.mean())
```

Current output using print:

```
Bird, B                 3302          1               4.38 2.62 4.62 4.62
Grouch, O               2201          2               4.23 2.69 4.00 4.23
                                      3               4.68 3.42 4.42 4.42
                        3303          2               3.80 2.85 3.25 3.65
                        4425          1               4.50 3.50 4.00 4.88  
Monster, C              3312          1               4.52 3.22 4.09 4.22
```

Thanks for any guidance.  -Tom

Answer (score -1):

According to your needs, you can:

- Write your code in a [Jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org), the `DataFrame` will look nicer formatted in HTML. There is also an option to export the notebook to PDF (it will require pdflatex).
- Export the `DataFrame` to Excel by using the `to_excel` [method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and format it according to your needs before integration. Note that you can also export to CSV (`to_csv`) to do the same thing.
- Use the `to_latex` method to produce an export that can be integrated in your latex source. A full example is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380371/export-a-latex-table-from-pandas-dataframe)
- Use the [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) package to produce a nicely formatted pure text output.

Hope it helps.